# Javascript Framework for a drawing/painting application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frameworks, draw

I am a noob javascript dev, but I have a project that I intend to provide.
It is basically a drawing application.

I already made a first version in native canvas and react: https://github.com/201flaviosilva/Rupestre

For a second version I would like to use a framework that simplifies development, I've been testing with fabricjs, but it didn't seem to have many specific features for my goal, I would like to know if you know any lib / framework that could be useful in this idea of mine ?

(Sorry, for my English) :)

Comment: Sorry to be annoying, but asking for frameworks is off-topic for stackoverflow. See [help/on-topic] for more information

Comment: https://d3js.org/